# How to make SCSS linter accept both snake lowercase and hyphenated lowercase as selectors naming convention

Tags: css, sass, scss-lint

My SCSS linter (`.scss-lint.yml`) is currently set to accept `hyphenated_lowercase` CSS selectors.

```
SelectorFormat:
  enabled: true
  convention: hyphenated_lowercase
```

Recently I've added couple of external widgets which are using `snake_case`. I need to target them within my SCSS files as well. The best solution would probably be to accept both snake case and hyphenated, both in lowercase. How can I achieve that?

I know I could also exclude the file containing those non-compliant rules, but I'm trying to avoid it for now.

Answer (score 1):

I found in [the official documentation](https://github.com/brigade/scss-lint/blob/master/lib/scss_lint/linter/README.md#selectorformat) that you can use a regular expression for selectors matching, therefore here's the solution:

```
SelectorFormat:
  enabled: true
  convention: ^[a-z\d_-]+$
```

Hope it will help others too.